# How do I generate tables / database schema from NHibernate mapping file (XML)

Tags: xml, nhibernate, orm, mapping

I have a XML file with all the information of a tables column names and types. How do I create that table in SQL Server 2008.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
    <class name="Op" table="op" dynamic-update="true">
    <id name="Id" column="id">
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>

    <property name="AccountId" column="account_id" not-null="true"/>
    <property name="Date" column="date" not-null="true" type="Timestamp"/>
    <property name="Amount" column="amount" not-null="true"/>

    <many-to-one name="AccountProp" column="account_id" 
                class="Account" not-null="true"/>


    <joined-subclass name="PayOperation" table="pay_operations">
        <key column="operation_id" />
```

Comment: no answers ??? Does anybody know what I am talking about ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perform schemaExport when you build the session factory.

e.g.

```
new SchemaExport(cfg).Execute(true, true, true);
```